# Ошибка при загрузке текстур на куб

Tags: javascript, three.js

Решил попробовать вставить различные текстуры в грани куба, нашёл пример кода, но у меня он выдаёт ошибку:

> HREE.WebGLRenderer: Texture is not
> power of two. Texture.minFilter is set
> to THREE.LinearFilter or
> THREE.NearestFilter. ( 1.png )
> three.min.js:556 Uncaught
> SecurityError: Failed to execute
> 'texImage2D' on
> 'WebGLRenderingContext': The
> cross-origin image at
> file:///D:/WebGL/cubeDiferent/1.png
> may not be loaded.

Сам код:

```
var material = 
[
new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map:THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('1.png')}),
new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map:THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('2.png')}), 
new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map:THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('3.png')}), 
new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map:THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('4.png')}), 
new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map:THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('5.png')}),
new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map:THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('6.png')})
];
            var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(80,80,80,3,3,3);
            var mat = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(material);
            var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,mat);
            scene.add(cube);
```

Comment: вся проблема в cross-origin, где запускается скрипт?

Comment: Тоесть где запускается скрипт? На локалке или не серваке, или в какой части документа?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот здесь у человека что-то подобное: http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=507&cpage=3#comment-583303

Может поможет.

Comment: Перенёс на локальный сервер ошибкой меньше, но рендерится не хочет:

    HREE.WebGLRenderer: Texture is not power of two. Texture.minFilter is set to THREE.LinearFilter or THREE.NearestFilter. ( 1.png )

Comment: Не поможет?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28289132/three-js-local-texture-loading-works-but-not-remotely

Как бы в google в первых пяти строчках.

Comment: Ошибка оказалось в строчке:
new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map:THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('1.png')
Нужно было поменять MeshLambert на MeshBasic